# Maven Spring Boot Compilation Failed

Tags: maven, spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to build `spring-boot` 2.0.0.RELEASE app using `maven` which will be deployed to `Heroku`. 
I am using IntelliJ for development, but `maven` gives compilation error with command `mvn spring-boot:run` / `mvc clean install`.

My `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>com.hms</groupId>
<artifactId>Hyatt</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>Hyatt</name>

<properties>
    <springsecurity.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.2.31</kotlin.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Heroku -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web Server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>


    <!--Kotlin-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-js</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>js</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-js</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>Hyatt</finalName>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <name>Spring Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

```
[INFO] Building Hyatt 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ Hyatt >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ Hyatt ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ Hyatt ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files to /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/controller/HotelController.java:[4,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/controller/HotelController.java:[5,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/controller/HotelController.java:[6,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/controller/HotelController.java:[7,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/UserService.java:[4,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/UserService.java:[5,26] package com.hms.repository does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/RoomService.java:[4,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/RoomService.java:[5,26] package com.hms.repository does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/BookingService.java:[3,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/BookingService.java:[4,26] package com.hms.repository does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/RoomTypeService.java:[3,21] package com.hms.model does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/service/RoomTypeService.java:[4,26] package com.hms.repository does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/controller/HotelController.java:[157,51] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Booking
  location: class com.hms.controller.HotelController
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/controller/HotelController.java:[190,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RoomType
  location: class com.hms.controller.HotelController
[ERROR] /home/adil/Idea Projects/Hotel-Management-System-Course-Project-/src/main/java/com/hms/controller/AdminController.java:[95,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class User
[ERROR] location: class com.hms.controller.AdminController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Hyatt: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 24 more
```

I am also using `Kotlin` for data classes and `Java` for other classes.
This is my first time building with `maven` so I am unable to fix this issue.

The project is available at [github](https://github.com/adilxiqbal/Hotel-Management-System)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Java code is being compiled before your Kotlin code has been compiled. As a result, the Java code that depends on the Kotlin code fails to compile.

The solution is [described in Kotlin's documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources). You need to update your pom so that Kotlin compilation is performed before Java compilation by disabling the default Java compilation goals:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. Should've read `Kotlin` documentation on maven integration.